Ubuntu 22.04 cracking sound
The sound on speakers only on Ubuntu 22.04 is cracking/mechanical. I searched for similar problems but people usually have issues with headphones only. Could you help me with that, please?

Details please. What apps? What have you tried to fix it?

How have you ruled out whether it is a software issue or hardware issue?

I haven't tried anything yet apart from searching the web, however, I didn't find a similar problem.
